# Setting user default and then immediately retrieving it gives nil

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Around 3 months ago I was working on a Swift project. Everything worked fine when I had stopped progress. I recently came back to the project, and every single place that I access UserDefaults I'm getting a nil response. It seems that the logic I'm using to set or retrieve the defaults is, for some reason, no longer working.

I have a global variable

```
let DEFAULTS = UserDefaults.standard()
```

And then in my ViewController.viewDidLoad(),

```
let defaultColor = UIColor(red: 34/255, green: 34/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)
let colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: defaultColor)
DEFAULTS.set(colorData, forKey: "highlight")
```

So I've created a UIColor, converted it to a Data object, and stored it under the key "highlight". However, if I immediately add a line to retrieve this data, I get a `nil` response.

```
let highlightColorData: Data! = DEFAULTS.object(forKey: "highlight") as! Data
let highlightColor: UIColor! = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: highlightColorData) as! UIColor
```

To clarify, the first line here is what's returning `nil` and thus crashing. It's complaining that I'm trying to force-unwrap a nil object. I have absolutely no idea why this would not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to do `synchronize` for it to be written immediately.

Comment: @Brandon hmm.. adding `DEFAULTS.synchronize()` after setting the data is not fixing the issue

Comment: @AustinSchiebel try printing color data please

Comment: What's the practical purpose to read the value back immediately?

Comment: @M.Kremer it is correctly printing a data object `<62706c69 73743030 d4010203 ... 00000000 00000000 00000130>`

Comment: Are you working in a playground by any chance?

Comment: @PhillipMills nope. I am using xcode-beta though. Perhaps there's an update that I need to install

Comment: I'm using XCode-Beta-6. Code works fine. Although there's a few minor syntax differences.. `UserDefaults.standard` (without the function brackets operator).

Comment: Well that's kinda frustrating. I guess it must be an issue somewhere else in my project then, and the error message isn't accurate.

Comment: Try to use dataForKey method to fetch the color back from preferences

Comment: Voting to close this question, on the grounds that the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your syntax so I tried writing it in the way I would write it and it worked. (Maybe they changed the syntax at Xcode 8.x):

```
    let DEFAULTS = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let defaultColor = UIColor(red: 34/255, green: 34/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)
    let colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(defaultColor)
    DEFAULTS.setObject(colorData, forKey: "highlight")
    let highlightColorData: NSData! = DEFAULTS.objectForKey("highlight") as! NSData
    let highlightColor: UIColor! = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(highlightColorData) as! UIColor
    print(highlightColor)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. The syntax has changed, but even following your logic my app is not working. I'll have to figure out where else the problem might be

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this (Xcode 8 seed 6) and it works fine for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let DEFAULTS = UserDefaults.standard

    let defaultColor = UIColor(red: 34/255, green: 34/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)
    let colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: defaultColor)
    DEFAULTS.set(colorData, forKey: "highlight")
    let highlightColorData = DEFAULTS.object(forKey: "highlight") as! Data
    print(highlightColorData as NSData) // <62706c69...
}
```